# Can Ultimate Toad spit mucus?

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers, toads-spit

I was reading a Wikipedia article the other day and noticed under [Ultimate Toad's power list](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mortimer_Toynbee_(Earth-1610)#Powers), one was stated as: the ability to spit a thick mucus-slime that hardens into a thick shell. Now, I could be wrong, but I don't recall seeing Toad use this attack, which would probably have almost the exact same effects as the film slime.

So, my question: **Has Ultimate Toad ever been shown to use mucus-slime in any of the Earth-1610 "Ultimate" comics?**

Comment: FWIW, the Marvel wiki also lists this as a power (which makes sense, as the movies are largely derived from the Ultimate versions of the characters.) http://marvel.wikia.com/Mortimer_Toynbee_(Earth-1610)

Comment: Much like the magic rock that I carry in my pocket that helps ward off tiger attacks in the jungle, the absence of examples does not necessarily mean that it is not true.

Comment: @phantom42 Homer Simpson would disagree.

Comment: @phantom42: It would probably depend on whether the edit came from an official source. That said, I think that it might be better if the question were "Has Ultimate Toad ever shown the ability to spit mucus-slime in the comics?" to clarify that they're looking for actual evidence of use.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Correct, and Marvel Wikia is not an official source, and interestingly Marvel's site does not have a listing for Ultimate-Toad. It does note that the Earth-616 Toad *does* have those powers now.

Answer (score 3):

If he can, he doesn't use it or indicate that he can.

In battle, Toad of Earth-1610 primarily leaps onto opponents and grapples them with his tongue. In situations where he's close enough and has a clear shot, he still uses his tongue:

[image]
[image]
[image]

None of the dialogue around the character seems to indicate that he has spit powers.

Something else of note is that there's never even a hint of spittle or slime coming from his mouth, even when we see his face close up. By all accounts, spitting is not an *ultimate* power. The Wikia quote is probably just an assumption based on most incarnations.

[image]